# How to migrate Clearcase repo to AccuRev?

Tags: clearcase, accurev

I want to migrate my source code from clearcase to AccuRev. I searched in google and accurev site for migration document. But I couldn't able to find any specific document for migration. Can anyone please help me in this.

Thanks,
Blexon.

Comment: It depends. Do you want to migrate everything (all branches, labels, versions, etc.) or just take the latest code and move it to AccuRev?

Comment: I Want everything to migrate from Clearcase to Accurev

Comment: Actually we are now doing POC for Migration and I want the migration document if any to proceed with further step.

Comment: With AccuRev the best resources would be from their own support site with a support login.  If you have the product or trial version you should be able to get some level of support from them.  That would be the quickest route.

Comment: I believe AccuRev has a migration tool for CC.  Talk to your technical rep regarding this.